# Running nodejitsu's Forever on Ubuntu - Cannot find module './daemon.v0.10.21'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, forever

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Node v0.10.21

This is the output from the terminal.

```
$ forever

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './daemon.v0.10.21'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/daemon/lib/daemon.js:12:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo rm -R /usr/lib/node_modules/forever
$ sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever

sudo npm install forever -g
```

Comment: Answers that begin with `sudo rm -R` **really** need text explaining what your intention for the command is and why you are suggesting starting out with that. Particularly when trying that prior to `npm install -g forever`.